# jQuery selector to last row first column

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to change the value of the first cell on the last row of a table.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.class tr:last td:first').html('Value');     
});
```

But that code changes nothing, but if I put without the :last and :first he fills the all table with 'Value'. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: My bad, the code works fine, but just for the last table with class 'class'.What I need it's to do that on every tables with that class. Any idea?

Comment: What's your mark-up look like, because [that seems to work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u6KuJ/1/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your edit, use `:last-child` and `:first-child` instead so it applies to the last `td` in the last `tr` of *every* `table.class`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.class tr:last-child td:first-child').html('Value');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine.

See http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/sJGZj/

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code and it works for me. Though I would change it to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('table#myTable tr:last td:first').html('Value');
        });

    </script>
```

Identifying the particular table you want to change. table.class will effect every table on the page.